# Hadoop wordcount - reduce method print 1 file result to a single 1 line

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop and I am stuck in how to reduce 1 file result in 1 line only.Like this format

```
[filename   v1,v2,v3...,v100]
```

I tried to print it as ArrayWritable, and the result is like:

```
a [255]
for[255,24]
to [255,24,10]
```

and so on

But really I want to print is

```
[filename 473,255, 30,....,v100]
```

group all of them in 1 line only, and not separate it based on the key.

The input is a article, like `(To Sherlock Holmes she is always THE woman. I have seldom heard him mention her under any other name. In his eyes she eclipses ......)`

The output format should be “[filename v1, v2, v3…, v100]”.

- `v1,v2...,v100` mean the value in vector.
- v1 mean the wordcount of the word " the",
- v2 mean the wordcount of the word "be"

I'm stuck on printing the result at the above format. I only need to print the array one time only, but it repeat to print in each time

```
public class WordCount implements Tool{
     private final static String[] top100Word = { "the", "be", "to", "of", "and", "a", "in", "that", "have", "i",
                "it", "for", "not", "on", "with", "he", "as", "you", "do", "at", "this", "but", "his", "by", "from", "they",
                "we", "say", "her", "she", "or", "an", "will", "my", "one", "all", "would", "there", "their", "what", "so",
                "up", "out", "if", "about", "who", "get", "which", "go", "me", "when", "make", "can", "like", "time", "no",
                "just", "him", "know", "take", "people", "into", "year", "your", "good", "some", "could", "them", "see",
                "other", "than", "then", "now", "look", "only", "come", "its", "over", "think", "also", "back", "after",
                "use", "two", "how", "our", "work", "first", "well", "way", "even", "new", "want", "because", "any",
                "these", "give", "day", "most", "us" };
     private  static Vector<Integer> vec = new Vector<Integer>(100);
    // private  static ArrayList<IntWritable> list = new ArrayList<IntWritable>();  
     private  static StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
     private static String[][] myArray = new String[10][100];


public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            vec.setSize(100);
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
} 

public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

int sum=0;
for (IntWritable val : values) {
     sum += val.get();

}



String finalVal = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("");

  for(int i=0;i<top100Word.length;i++){

     Text topValue = new Text(top100Word[i]);
    // vec.add(i,sum);
      if(key.equals(topValue)){
          System.out.println("hi");
          System.out.println("key"+key);
          System.out.println(i);
            vec.add(i,sum);

            //result.set(sum);  //sum= count number
             //  context.write(key, result);
            sb.append(sum);
            String strI = sb.toString();
        myArray[0][i] = strI;
            //list.add(i,new IntWritable(sum));

               if(str.length() > 0)
                  {
                      str.append(",");
                  }
                  str.append(myArray[0][i].toString());





         context.write(key, new Text(str.toString()));

        //  context.write(key, new Text(myArray[0][i]));
            break;
            }
  }





}

}

public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Configuration conf = new Configuration();
       String[] files=new GenericOptionsParser(conf,args).getRemainingArgs();
        Path dst_path = new Path(files[0]);
        Path in_path1 = new Path(files[1]);
        Path in_path2 = new Path(files[2]);
        Path in_path3 = new Path(files[3]);
        FileSystem hdfs = dst_path.getFileSystem(conf);

        if (hdfs.exists(dst_path)){
            hdfs.delete(dst_path, true);
           };


    //Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
     Job job = new Job(conf,"word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

 // map output types
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    // reducer output types

    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);


    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, in_path1, TextInputFormat.class, Map.class);
  //  MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, in_path2, TextInputFormat.class, Map.class);
   // MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, in_path3, TextInputFormat.class, Map.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
   // FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, dst_path);

    return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


      int ecode = ToolRunner.run(new WordCount(), args);

      for(int i=0 ;i<vec.size();i++){

              System.out.println(vec.get(i)+",");
        //  context.write(lastkey,new MyArrayWritable(IntWritable.class, list.toArray(new IntWritable[vec.get(i)])));

      }
      for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
       if(str.length() > 0)
          {
              str.append(",");
          }
          str.append(myArray[0][i].toString());

      }

      System.out.println(str);


      System.exit(ecode);
     }

@Override
public Configuration getConf() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setConf(Configuration arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the given input, the expected output and where within the code you are stuck?

Comment: The input is a article, like   (To Sherlock Holmes she is always THE woman. I have seldom heard

him mention her under any other name. In his eyes she eclipses

......)

Comment: The output format should be “[filename v1, v2, v3…, v100]”, e.g.,
file_1_name 1, 2, 3, 4, …, 100. v1,v2...,v100 mean the value in vector

Comment: I stuck in print all wordcount result in 1 line

Comment: v1 mean the wordcount of the word " the", v2 mean the wordcount of the word "be".

Comment: I only need to print the array one time only, but it repeat to print in each time

Comment: Please add everything that is relevant to the question, not to the comment section. And is the problem now gathering the data or printing it? What have you tried to debug that?

Comment: I think the problem is gathering data, I have try to use a vector to store the data to print out once only at last. But it print out it time. And I can not sort the result based on the top100Words[]

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding that one line means one reducer's `context.write` usage. It's not clear why you're expecting the filename to be the key, but since it isn't, and the mapper outputs only the word and the key, you're getting multiple lines in the output, one per word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only expecting the filename to be a single key, you can't just use WordCount as your example code...

Actually think about what output you're getting from the mapper into the reducer. For example, it's not clear where you're getting a filename from. Ideally, that comes from the mapper Context, if possible.

The output your mapper generates is currently split across multiple lines, with no reference to which file they come from

```
(To, 1)
(Sherlock, 1) 
(Holmes, 1)
(she, 1)
(she, 1)
```

And so on. And capitalization matters unless you explicitly lowercase the tokens.

My suggestion for you is to rather output some information about the filename, as well as, sum the words of a line **within the mapper**. One line of the file will output one Reducer record like this

```
(filename, To=1; Sherlock=1; Holmes=1; she=2)
```

The next line of the file would produce a similar record, with the filename key the same, and the value text as different.

So then, what the reducer will see is a single Text key with an iterable list of Text entries

```
(filename, ["To=1; Sherlock=1; Holmes=1; she=2", "..."])
```

All you then must do is to extract the value text, and summarize it for each `word=count` pairing.

And finally, please do the "top word" check within the mapper code, not the reducer. Otherwise, you're wasting resources in the mapper that you don't care about.

Here's a starting point for the mapper

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    private static final HashMap<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
    private Text output = new Text();

    private String mapToString(Map<String, Object> map) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, Object> entry = iter.next();
            sb.append(entry.getKey());
            sb.append('=');
            sb.append(entry.getValue().toString());
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                sb.append(';').append(' ');
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO: Get filename
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
            if (!counter.containsKey(token)) {
                counter.put(token, 1);
            } else {
                counter.put(token, (Integer) counter.get(token) + 1);
            }
        }
        output.set(mapToString(counter));
        context.write(new Text("filename"), output);
    }
}
```

I'll leave the reducer implementation up to you. Keep in mind that this code requires you to `extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>`